# org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate is pure hibernate or JPA implemenation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

As shown in below code snippet, I am using the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate` for data access in my DAO. Does it mean that I am mixing hibernate and JPA in this case?

I have read so far that we should not mix both JPA and Hibernate in the data access mechanism. we should always stick to either purely hibernate(`org.hibernate.*` API) or Hibernate implementation of JPA(`java.persistance.`* API). But with hibernate integration, we are not using either pure Hibernate or JPA? is that correct or I misunderstood the concept.

Basically I would like to know the spring provided integration style of hibernate is best practice for data access?

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    protected org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
            template = null;

    @Resource(name = "abcSessionFactory")
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void init(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        template = new org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.
                HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

below is my contex.xml configuration

```
<bean id="abcSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="abcDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan"
            value="xxxx" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${hibernate.connection.driver.class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">${hibernate.current_session_context_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that I am mixing hibernate and JPA in this case?

No, `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate` is helper that works with hibernate `Session`.
It uses standard [org.hibernate.Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) methods, like [get()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29). Here is [source of HibernateTemplate.get()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java#L516).

By the way, in `DAOImpl` you are using both SessionFactory and HibernateTemplate. Is it really necessary ? Please consider that `HibernateTemplate` creates new `Session` by default, see [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html).

If you choose to use `HibernateTemplate` only, code may look like:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {

   @Autowired
   protected org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate template;

}
```

Configuration:

```
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <!-- use hibernate SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() for getting session -->
    <property name="allowCreate" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks, updated my post with the configuration details. are they wrong?

Comment: All seems to be OK. Better to check it with your model.